# Are $ reboot and $ shutdown -r now different?

Tags: 12.04, bash, fsck

I was receiving the following notification at the end of my message of the day

`*** /dev/xvda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***`

I did the following

```
$ touch /forcefsck
$ shutdown -r now
```

But when I rebooted `/forcefsck` still existed and I was receiving the same warning at the end of the message of the day.  I then ran

```
$ reboot
```

And now I longer receive the error at the end of the message of the day (I assume running `fsck` correctly this problem)

Comment: I don't think so. Both Command do same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manpage for `reboot` says:

> When called with --force or when in runlevel 0 or 6, this tool 
>   invokes the reboot(2) system call itself and directly reboots the
>   system.  Otherwise this simply invokes the shutdown(8) tool  with 
>   the  appropriate arguments.

So in most cases `reboot` just calls `shutdown -r`.